# Match double '&&' char or double '||' in regex

Tags: regex

`&{2}` could match double '&&' char(in other words - a `AND` operator), everything goes as my expect. However, `[&{2}|\|{2}]` will match single '&' or '|' char . How can I do for the case and why the case occur?

Comment: In what language? Please re-tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[]` is a character group, i.e. *"any character within this group."* Special characters do not have any or not the same meaning within it. Use a regular group:

```
(&{2}|\|{2})
```

If you want it to be non-capturing:

```
(?:&{2}|\|{2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
/([&|])\1/

()   - capture
[&|] - character class which matches a single & or |
\1   - and match what has been captured
```

matches and doubled & or |

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `[]` in this case.

```
&{2}|\|{2}
```

Example of usage:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /&{2}|\|{2}/' <<EOF
> &&
> ||
> |
> EOF
&&
||
```

As you can see `&&` and `||` were matched and `|` not.